# Neo4j query in neo4j-sh returns the right number of rows while query_as in RoR returns double the number of rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Here are my classes, I am following the example provided at: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/tree/master/example/blog
The application so far works for CRUD operations.
Here are my model classes:

```
class Post
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :title
  property :description
  validates :title, presence: true
  index :title
  has_many :out, :comments, rel_class: PostComment
end

class Comment
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :body
  index :body
  has_one :in, :post, rel_class: PostComment
end

class PostComment
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel
  from_class Post
  to_class Comment
  type 'has_comments'
  property :created_at
end
```

I have 2 Posts. Post 1 has 3 Comments and Post 2 has one Comment. For comments in total.
When I a run this query from the neo4j-shell I am getting the right number of records.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node(*) match n-[:has_comments]->(m) return n,m;
4 rows
30 ms
```

This is correct.
Now trying something similar form RoR I am getting 8 rows instead of 4.

```
2.1.5 :012 >   result = Post.query_as(:post).match("posts-[:has_comments]->(comment:Comment)").pluck(:post, :comment)
2.1.5 :014 > result.count
 => 8
```

Can't see what is wrong here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect 6 rows, not 8, but maybe I'm overlooking something. Doesn't matter, really. Instead of returning post and comment independently, try returning `post` and collections of `comment`. You don't need `query_as`, either, you can do it purely through QueryProxy.

```
result = Post.as(:post).comments(:comment).pluck(:post, 'collect(comment)')
result.each do |pair|
  post = pair[0]
  comments_array = pair[1]
  comments_array.each do |comment|
    # do things
  end
end
```

We're going to have an `includes` method in soon that will automate most of this for you, you'll just be able to do `Post.all.includes(:comments)` and then `post.comments.each` won't result in an extra query.

Also note that the match you wrote in wrote in the shell isn't the same as what the gem is going to generate. Call `to_cypher` on your query prior to `pluck` to see what it's building. It own't include the `return` statement, so add that on: `RETURN post, comment` if you want to do it as is. The gem's Cypher is a little messy as of the latest release but it'll be cleaner in the next one.

Comment: The first statement is not syntactically correct, I guess, it is returning an error:

Comment: result = Post.as(:post).comments(:comment).pluck(:post, 'collect(comment')
Neo4j::Session::CypherError: Unexpected end of input: expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ')' (line 1, column 119)
"MATCH (post:`Post`), (comment:`Comment`), post-[rel1:`has_comments`]->(comment:`Comment`) RETURN post, collect(comment"

Comment: I fixed the syntax error and now that coed works well.

Comment: result = Post.as(:post).comments(:comment).pluck(:post,'collect(comment)')
result.count
result.each do |pair|
  post = pair[0]
  puts post.title, post.description
  comments_array = pair[1]
  comments_array.each do |comment|
    puts comment.body
  end
  puts
end

Comment: returning RoR
Application framework
Works with any database

Ne4j
Graph database
For Neo4j the ActiveModel was replaced by ActiveNode and ActiveRelationship
Is a graph database
Has a gem for RoR

Comment: Sorry, I missed that closing parenthesis. Not sure what you're trying to say with that last comment...?

Comment: I wanted to show that the returned results are correct, my little blog about Neo4j and RoR works, many thanks.